# Acceder a un atributo de un HashMap para una vista .ftl con Java

Tags: java, maven

Estoy intentando acceder a un atributo de un objeto `Java` pero no lo consigo. Tengo el controlador donde creo el objeto y le añado los datos:

```
    Email emailModel = new Email();

    buildMailModel(emailModel);

    Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<>();
    root.put("EmailModel", emailModel);

    private static void buildMailModel(Email emailModel) {

        List<ComponentBase> components = getComponents();

        emailModel.setComponents(components);

        emailModel.setDocument(getNewsDocument());

        emailModel.setDestinataries(getDestinataries());

        emailModel.setShippingConfiguration(getShippingConfiguration());

    }
```

Esto me crea el objeto con esta estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces intento acceder al atributo `title` en el `.ftl` de la siguiente manera, pero no lo consigo:

```
${emailModel.document.title}
```

Comment: Es que no tiene sentido iterar un elemento unico. Para iterar necesitas tener una coleccion.

Comment: @JDev perdon, no es iterar sino acceder a ese atributo

Comment: No se si será eso pero lo estas pasando como `EmailModel` y lo recuperas en el ftl como `emailModel`

Comment: @JDev, tienes razon, es eso, el problema que como no sacaba por consola, no se por que no lo muestra, ahora lo saco en un documento .html y si que lo muestra. Gracias!

Comment: @JDev y como puedo iterar ahora sobre la arrayList de components?

Comment: Con `<#list LISTA as ELEMENTO>` y `</#list>`. Lo que introduzcas dentro se ejecutará por cada elemento. Echa un vistazo a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981495/passing-a-list-of-objects-to-freemarker-and-then-looping